# Codehs grid diagonally

Tags: javascript, grid

The assignment:
Write a function that returns a list of the diagonal elements in a square grid.

`function getDiagonal(grid, whichDiagonal)`
The diagonals are named by the constants at the top of the program.

```
var DIAGONAL_TOP_LEFT_BOTTOM_RIGHT = 0;
var DIAGONAL_BOTTOM_LEFT_TOP_RIGHT = 1;
```

For example, given the grid grid with these contents:

```
4   2   5
1   8   3
7   3   9
```

The call of `getDiagonal(grid, DIAGONAL_TOP_LEFT_BOTTOM_RIGHT)` should return an array with contents:

`[4, 8, 9]`

Now test your function by calling it several times, and printing out the grid.

My code prints ", , ," and I'm not sure why here is my full code:

```
var DIAGONAL_TOP_LEFT_BOTTOM_RIGHT = 0;
var DIAGONAL_BOTTOM_LEFT_TOP_RIGHT = 1;

function start(){
    var grid = new Grid(3, 3);
    grid.initFromArray([
        ["4", "2", "5"],
        ["1", "8", "3"],
        ["7", "3", "9"]
    ]);
    getDiagonal(grid, DIAGONAL_TOP_LEFT_BOTTOM_RIGHT);
}

function getDiagonal(grid, whichDiagonal){
    var diagonalList = [];
        for(var row = 0; row<grid.numRows() + 1; row++){
        for(var col = 0; col<grid.numCols() + 1; col++){
            if(row == col){
                var curr = grid.get[row, col];
                diagonalList.push(curr);
            
            }
        }
    }
    println(diagonalList);
}
```

I'm also not sure how to use the 2 given variables at the top

Answer (score 0):

there are two problems in your code in this function:

```js
function getDiagonal(grid, whichDiagonal){
    var diagonalList = [];
        for(var row = 0; row<grid.numRows() + 1; row++){
        for(var col = 0; col<grid.numCols() + 1; col++){
            if(row == col){
                var curr = grid.get[row, col];
                diagonalList.push(curr);
            
            }
        }
    }
    println(diagonalList);
}
```

Change it to this:

```js
function getDiagonal(grid, whichDiagonal){
    var diagonalList = [];
        for(var row = 0; row<grid.numRows(); row++){
        for(var col = 0; col<grid.numCols(); col++){
            if(row == col){
                var curr = grid.get(row, col);
                diagonalList.push(curr);
            
            }
        }
    }
    println(diagonalList);
}
```